# How to explain delegate in an Interview

Tags: c#

I know we have lot of similar type question in Stackoverflow, also I know what is delegate and how it works, but sometimes  it's a bit difficult to explain delegate in interviews, any suggestion on how to explain it?

Comment: If you truly understood delegates, you wouldn't have a problem explaining them in an interview. I suggest studying.

Comment: Also, just in case, for interview you should remember what is the difference between Delegate and Event :)

Answer (score 5):

It's a strongly typed function pointer, essentially.  It's a way to pass arbitrary code as a method parameter.

Comment: A _strongly typed_ function pointer.

Comment: +1 for you @Oded, good correction.

Comment: One really important part is that it's not only a function pointer, but that it can contain a bound first argument(typcially this) too. Else it wouldn't work with instance methods.

Comment: OK, so *what's a function pointer*?  This is an explanation that doesn't explain anything unless you already know what a "function pointer" is. Why should a C# programmer happen to know this concept from C?

Comment: And can you really pass "arbitrary code"?  "class C{}" is perfectly valid code, as is "[Obsolete]" and "using System;" but none of those get passed around in delegates.

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is a C# language element that allows you to reference a method.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the ways I've heard  delegates being described:

- Language and framework support for first-class functions.
- Single-method interfaces.
- Type-safe function pointers.
- Objects representing a sequence of operations with a well-defined contract.

---

If probed for more detail, I would:

- Distinguish between System.Delegate, delegate-*types*, delegate-type *variables* and delegate-*instances*;  elaborate on their declaration, assignment, passing and invocation.
- Emphasize their immutable reference-type nature.
- Discuss multicast delegates.
- List some of the common delegate types in the framework, especially the Func<> and Action<> families.
- Tie delegates in with method-groups, anonymous methods, lambda-expressions and closures. Explain the uses of the `delegate` keyword in C# as well as the various courtesies accorded to the programmer by the compiler
- Discuss their relationship with threading, events, expression-trees and LINQ.
- Discuss:

  - Higher-order functions - currying, combinators etc.
  - How delegates can be used with reflection.
  - Variance with respect to delegates.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the real live analogy?

http://www.wordreference.com/definition/delegate

> entrust (a task or responsibility) to another person (in this case would be a method).

In computing word, you could explain this in the same way. When you pass a delegate to a method, you don't know about the implementation of the method, simply is a reference to that method, and the delegate takes care of executing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an entity which encapsulates method signature and provides a type-safe, object-oriented mechanism for treating functions as objects without having to use function pointers.